# How does `date` calculate time zone offset?

Tags: linux, date

If I set the time zone environment variable: `TZ="Foo/Bar"`, how does `date` handle different time zones and display the date accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

GNU utils use the [tz database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) that contains a representation of current, future and historical timezones and transform the output accordingly.

### Long answer

Run `info coreutils 'date input formats'` if you have the full manual installed and read onwards for context, and specifically read **28.10 Specifying time zone rules**. If the manual is not installed, you can read it [read it online](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html).

### Appendix

Dates, time and time zones are *really tricky* to keep track of :-) .